# Show popup for map marker when hovering marker AND popup, hide popup when hovering out

Tags: jquery, css

I have a map with lots of markers on it.

When you hover over the blue dots, the popup appears and it disappears when you unhover from it again - is it possible to make it so that
you can move the mouse cursor up into the address speech bubble without the bubble disappearing?

Here's the jsfiddle (it doesn't quite look correct but enough to show as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/po6t75jf/

Here's my jquery:

```
// Contact us map with popups
$(".feature").hover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.map-popup[data-number], .map-down-arrow[data-number]').hide();

  var item = $(this).data('number');
  $('.map-popup[data-number="' + item + '"]').show();
  $('.map-down-arrow[data-number="' + item + '"]').show();
  var title = $('.map-popup-title[data-number="' + item + '"]').text();
  $('#input_2_5').find('option[value="' + title + '"]').attr('selected', true);
},
function () {
    $('.map-popup, .map-down-arrow').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".feature, .map-popup").hover(function(e) {
```

The thing you need to do is: add the same hover effect on the map-info-location container (.map-popup), and connect the two elements so there is room for the user to move his his mouse from the dot location to the container location, so in theory if the dot is hovered then both will popup but if you continue to hover one or the other both will show, if you hoverout map will fadeout, the way you can connect the dot and the map-info container is:

var hoverElement = $('.overlay');
// element that fadesIn on dot hover, and has the same properties of the dot, while //covering the dot and the map-location-info, once the dot is hovered.
//ofcourse that element has to be absolutely positioned with transparent background.

```
$(".feature,.hoverElement").hover(function(e) {
```

//same code

Hope I helped, I am sorry about not posting a more detailed answer, but I'm at work currently, maybe Ill post tonight if you cant figure it out :).
Thank you!

Comment: If you just add , .map-popup to your hover jquery selector, it almost works :) , you just have to snap really fast to the map-popup, you just need to do it smoother now, like i said in the comment above, make a special element that appears (transparently) after dot hover/click, and have that same element have a hover to display those elements that the dot displayed.

Comment: Just adding `.map-popup` worked... think if I did anything else then it'd cause other issues. Thanks.